# Call function from another script only once in Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I'm having trouble with some countdown timer functionality. In my GameManager script I'm checking the scene name and checking for idle usage (no mouse movement/no clicking) and kicking off a function in my CountdownTimer script that is counts down the amount of idle time using the function StartPreCountTimer(). Once that timer reaches zero it then instantiates a countdown dialog and kicks off IEnumerator RunTimer() that the user can either cancel to continue playing or let reach zero, at which point the game resets and returns to the intro screen.

The problem I'm having is at the precount step. The GameManager script keeps calling StartPreCountTimer() every frame which obviously prevents the countdown from ever completing because it restarts every frame. How do I fix this? How do a call the function only once from Update?

**GameManager Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static GameManager gameManagerInstance = null; // Create Singleton

    public GameObject loader;
    public GameObject countdownTimer;

    public Color defaultBackgroundColor;                 
    public Object startingScene;
    public GameObject timeOutWarningDialog;
    public float countdownLength;
    public float countdownDelay;

    private Vector3 prevMousePosition;
    private CountdownTimer countdownInstance;
    private Scene currentScene;
    private GameObject gameManager;
    private GameObject canvas;

    public static string animalDataFilePathJSON;
    public static string animalDataFilePathTex;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (gameManagerInstance == null)
            gameManagerInstance = this;
        else if (gameManagerInstance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        gameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager");

        // get and store JSON and Tex filepaths defined in Loader script
        animalDataFilePathJSON = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Loader").GetComponent<Loader>().animalDataFilePathJSON;
        animalDataFilePathTex = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Loader").GetComponent<Loader>().animalDataFilePathTex;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

        countdownInstance = countdownTimer.GetComponent<CountdownTimer>(); // Create an instance of CountdownTimer
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

        if (currentScene.name != startingScene.name)
        {
            countdownInstance.StartPreCountTimer(); // Start Pre-count Timer

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.mousePosition != prevMousePosition)
            {
                countdownInstance.StartPreCountTimer(); // Start Pre-count Timer

                if (timeOutWarningDialog != null)
                    timeOutWarningDialog.SetActive(false);
            }
            prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        }
    }
}
```

**CountdownTimer Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject timeOutWarningDialog;
    public float countdownLength;
    public float countdownDelay;
    public Object startingScene;

    private float countdownInterval = 1;
    private GameObject countdownTimer;
    private IEnumerator counter;
    private Button stopCountButton;
    private Text timerTextField;
    private GameObject timerInstance;
    private GameObject canvas;

    // GAME TIMER

    public void StartPreCountTimer()
    {
        CancelInvoke();
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Timer") == null)
            Invoke("ShowRestartWarning", countdownDelay);
    }

    void ShowRestartWarning()
    {
        canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");

        timerInstance = Instantiate(timeOutWarningDialog); // instantiate timeout warning dialog
        timerInstance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        timerInstance.SetActive(true);

        Text[] textFields = timerInstance.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>(true); // get reference to timer textfields
        timerTextField = textFields[2]; // access and assign countdown textfield

        stopCountButton = timerInstance.GetComponentInChildren<Button>(); // get reference to keep playing button
        stopCountButton.onClick.AddListener(StopTimer); // add button listener

        if (timerInstance.activeSelf == true)
        {
            counter = RunTimer(countdownLength); // create new reference to counter, resets countdown to countdownLength
            StartCoroutine(counter);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RunTimer(float seconds)
    {
        float s = seconds;
        while (s > -1)
        {
            if (timerTextField != null)
                timerTextField.text = s.ToString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(countdownInterval);
            s -= countdownInterval;
        }

        if (s == -1)
        {
            RestartGame();
        }
    }

    void StopTimer()
    {
        StopCoroutine(counter);
        Destroy(timerInstance);
    }

    void RestartGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(startingScene.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using an event instead of calling a method at every Update cycle?

Comment: i'm not really familiar with events. any recommended places online to learn more?

Comment: I think I got your problem now! You may want to have a boolean variable that is set to `false` after the first `Update` is done and an `if` that checks if it is `true` at the beginning and only when it is `true`, you run your `StartPreCountTimer()`. This way you only set the timer once, or everytime you reset this boolean to `false`.

Comment: Thanks @MaxPlay , I'm actually working on that now. I had an epiphany that I was missing a bool while I was out for a run this morning. :/